# R histogram plot controlling x-axis values

Tags: r, histogram

I have the following two vectors

```
 x<-c(-525,-520,-515,-460,-455,-450);
 y<-c(6,20,976,20,16,78);
```

I would like to plot a histogram where y vector denotes the frequency and the x vector denotes the x-axis values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# create df with required frequency
m<-unlist(mapply(rep,x,y))
#check
table(m)
hist(m)
```

Comment: Better to just use hist(rep(x,y)) as in sdir's answer

Comment: That is a fine answer as well. Sorry, didn't see it before I made my post. I think it is even nicer than me as you get separate vectors when you use mapply!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
# replicate each element in x y-times
z <- rep(x,y)
hist(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(-525,-520,-515,-460,-455,-450), y=c(6,20,976,20,16,78))
barplot(dat$y, names.arg=dat$x, ylim=c(5,80), ylab=" frequency", xlab="x- Value")
```